# Mapbox GL JS : Live geoJSON overlay

Tags: geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on a weather app in Mapbox and trying to get geoJSON files to update tornado warning polygons live on the map. (This would be done by a file called "warnings.geojson" in the same path as the html file and re-written frequently by a back end c++ app). Anyway, I found the following example on how to update live JSON files :

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-geojson/

This works for what it is designed to do (and I understand what it is doing - it is what I am looking for), but I cannot seem to replace the code with my own. I would like to have it update the following test polygon file instead.

https://manidoo.000webhostapp.com/test.geoJSON

The above code is just a polygon of the Bermuda triangle. (Once I get this working, I can modify it on my own) I have tried so many variations of code that listing them here would just be a huge mess. Surely it should very simple and I am just missing it?

I believe what I should be changing is the map.addLayer() function, but I am not sure what to do. Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: The geojson you provided seems valid to me so it probably comes from your code. Could you provide at least the part you use to load your geojson in a source and use it in a layer?

Comment: I had just figured this out before seeing your reply. I was testing this offline and I use the Edge browser to test with since I am using image overlays (and they show in offline mode where Firefox and Chrome don't). However the polygons in Edge don't work in offline mode, where in Firefox they do.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to my own question was testing the app in the wrong browser. Edge will not show geoJSON polygons that are on a local directory (atleast in this specific scenario). As MeltedPenguin pointed out - the JSON was valid. Once I uploaded my HTML and geoJSON to a server online with a http:// prefix, it worked great. Firefox showed the polygon even in offline mode.